# Update Options in Wordpress Custom Post Type Options Page

Tags: wordpress, savechanges

I've created a file that adds an options page to a WP custom post type that is supposed to show options for a Slideshow and I'm having trouble saving the data. Basically when you click the submit button I want it to update the option. Thanks for the help :)

Here's my code:

{

```
<?php

    // Add Options in the database.
    add_option('slider_width', 960);
    add_option('slider_height', 350);


    // Create options to display.
    $prefix = 'slider';
    $options = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Slider Width',
            'desc' => 'Set the width of the slideshow in pixels.',
            'id' => $prefix.'_width',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Slider Height',
            'desc' => 'Set the height of the slideshow in pixels.',
            'id' => $prefix.'_height',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array( "type" => "close"),
        array( 'type' => 'section'),
        array( "type" => "open")

    ); // end $options

    // Add options page to admin area
    function slider_add_admin() {  
    global $prefix, $options;  


    if ( $_GET['page'] == 'slider_options' ) {  
        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {  
            foreach ($options as $value) {  
            update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }  
    foreach ($options as $value) {  
        if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }  
        header("Location: edit.php?post_type=sliders&page=slider_options&saved=true");  
    die;  
    }  
    else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {  
        foreach ($options as $value) {  
            delete_option( $value['id'] ); }  
        header("Location: edit.php?post_type=sliders&page=slider_options&reset=true");  
    die;  
    }  
    }

    // Create Subpage
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=sliders','Slider Page Options','Slider Options', 'edit_sliders', 'slider_options', slider_options);

    }

    function slider_options(){
        global $prefix, $options;  
        $i=0;  

        if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>Slider settings saved.</strong></p></div>';  
        if ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>Slider settings reset.</strong></p></div>';  

        ?>  
        <div class="wrap rm_wrap">  
        <h2>Slider Options</h2>  

        <div class="rm_opts">  
        <form method="post">

        <?php
        // Add cases for the options.
        foreach ($options as $value) {
        switch ( $value['type'] ) {

        case 'open':
        break;

        case 'close':?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <?php
        break;

        case 'text':
        echo '<label for="'.$value['id'].'">'.$value['name'].'</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$value['name'].'" id="'.$value['id'].'" value="';
            if( get_option($value['id']) != "" ){echo get_option($value['id']);}
        echo '" size="30" /><small class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</small>';
        break;

        case 'checkbox':
        echo '<label for="'.$value['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>';
        break;

        case 'section':
        $i++;
        echo '<div class="rm_section">';
        echo '<div class="rm_title"><h3><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/logo.png" class="inactive"/>';
        echo $value['name'];
        echo '</h3><span class="submit"><input name="save'.$i.'" type="submit" value="Save Changes" /></span>';
        echo '<div class="clearfix"></div></div>';

        break;
            } // end switch
        } //end foreach
        ?>
         <?php echo get_option('slider_width'); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
        </form>
        <form method="post">
        <p class="submit">
        <input name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
        </p>
        </form>
         </div> 


        <?php
        } // end slider_options
        add_action('admin_menu', 'slider_add_admin');
        ?>
```

}

Comment: The problem probably in your `header` command, when the page doesn't return to itself and not saving your data. what do you get when you click on submit? do you come back to your posts list? also, please try to change `&page=slider_options` in your `header` command to `&page=slider_options.php` and see if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you; I create options pages for the Dashboard a bit differently, but it allows me to create anything I want in the form. I include this file from functions.php. As an example, it saves a single input field, but you can make more fields by adding more lines like this:

register_setting( 'example_options_settings-group', 'example_some_other_field' );

And then the corresponding inputs in the example_options_settings_page() form.

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'example_options');

function example_options() {
    $icon_path = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/icon-plugin.png';
    add_menu_page('Options', 'Options', 'delete_others_pages', __FILE__, 'example_options_settings_page',$icon_path, 115);
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'example_options_settings' );
}

function example_options_settings() {
    register_setting( 'example_options_settings-group', 'example_contact_url' );
}

function example_options_settings_page() { ?>

<div class="wrap theme-options">

<div class="icon32" id="icon-options-general"><br /></div>

<h2>Theme Options</h2>

<form method="post" class="theme-options-form" action="options.php">

        <?php settings_fields( 'example_options_settings-group'); ?>

        <div class="postbox metabox-holder">
            <h3 class="hndle">Contact Info</h3>
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="option-panel">
                    <p><label for="example_contact_url">Enter Email Address</label></p>
                    <p>
                        <?php $example_contact_url = get_option('example_contact_url'); ?>
                        <input id="example_contact_url" name="example_contact_url" value="<?php echo $example_contact_url; ?>" style="width: 90%;" type="text" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<input type="hidden" value="1" />
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
    </p>
</form>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```